# How to bind textbox to listbox content when listbox is bound to another source?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a simple code and I’m trying to bind a TextBlock’s Text property to the ListBox but it doesn’t work!
I was trying to follow the instructions in this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx
Below is my code:

```
  <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MoreColors" XPath="Colors">
                <x:XData>                   
                    <Colors xmlns="">
                        <color name="Green"/>
                        <color name="Blue"/>
                    </Colors>
                </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <TextBlock Height="23" Name="textBlock1" TextAlignment="Center" 
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path= SelectedItem.Content, Mode=OneWay}"
                       Background="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Width="119" /> 

        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Width="248" Height="56" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MoreColors}, 
            XPath=color/@name}">
        </ListBox>



    </StackPanel>
```

I wonder how I can fix this problem.
Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is an XmlAttriute, bind to `InnerText`

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedItem.InnerText, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but then when I need to use SelectedItem.Content and when I need to use SelectedItem.InnerText or SelectedItem.Value?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Path= SelectedItem.Content` by `Path = SelectedItem.Value`

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but I wonder why the SelectedItem.Content doesn't work?

Comment: The object you are binding to is an XmlAttribute. Look it up in the MSDN and look at its properties. There is no Content property.

Comment: Oh! I see now! the SelectedItem is not a ListBoxItem!! What I was thinking!!?! Thank you guys.